# RESTful Methods in Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I've been developing controller actions that accept `Option[JsValue]` since Play's `request` object can be parsed as JSON:

```
def submit = Action { implicit request => 
  performDbQuery(request.body.asJson)
  ...
}

def performDbQuery(json: Option[JsValue]) = {
  ...
}
```

routes

`PUT /submit controllers.MainController.submit`

Is JSON the preferred way to issue REST calls in Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure Stack Overflow is the right place to ask about "preferred ways", but it certainly makes it very easy to work with JSON as you've seen.

You can actually tighten up your code even more by using a [Body Parser](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaBodyParsers) which will automagically reject requests to your `/submit` endpoint that don't have a `Content-Type` of `application/json`, returning a 400 code for you, and allowing stronger typing within your methods:

```
def submit = Action(parse.json) { implicit request => 
  performDbQuery(request.body)
  ...
}

def performDbQuery(json: JsValue) = {
  ...
}
```

Notice how the `Option` went away because we can be *sure* that it's good JSON at this point now.

Comment: As a follow-up, if I wanted to send a `List[String]` (explicitly that type), how would I handle the serialization & de-serialization (if any)?

Comment: You get it almost for free with Play's [JSON library](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaJson) - once you know you've got a `JsValue` as the `request.body` you can just do: `val myList = request.body.as[List[String]]`